# How to restrict the bootstrap timepicker min-time and max-time?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap time picker by using bootstrap-timepicker.js and i want to restrict the min-time and max-time of that timepicker .Can anyone please tell me how can i achieve it.
I have used following methods but nothing gonna help me out:

```
 $('input[data-role="time"]').timepicker({
    showMeridian: true,
    minTime: {
    hour: 10,
    minute: 15
    },
    minuteStep: 1,
    showInputs: true,
    defaultTime: defaulttime
    })
```

And

```
$('input[data-role="time"]').timepicker({
        showMeridian: true,
        minTime: '10:15',
        minuteStep: 1,
        showInputs: true,
        defaultTime: defaulttime
        })
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. use event `changeTime`,
2. check the current time,
3. if time is less set minimum

http://jsfiddle.net/j3kf2p2e/

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
        showMeridian: true,        
        minuteStep: 1,
        showInputs: true,        
}).on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {    
    var h= e.time.hours;
    var m= e.time.minutes;
    var mer= e.time.meridian;
    //convert hours into minutes
    m+=h*60;
    //10:15 = 10h*60m + 15m = 615 min
    if(mer=='AM' && m<615)
        $('#timepicker').timepicker('setTime', '10:15 AM');
  });
```

Comment: This solution throws a recursion exception because calling timepicker('setTime') will trigger the 'changeTime.timepicker' event. You shouldn't be calling 'setTime' inside of the 'changeTime' callback.

Comment: You can call 'setTime' inside 'changeTime' as long as it has a condition on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:eg if mindate is at 8.00 and maxdate is at 2300hrs

```
    minDate: moment({h:8}),
    maxDate: moment({h:23}),
```

that is...

```
$('#time').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    format: 'HH:mm',
    minDate: moment({h:8}),
    maxDate: moment({h:23}),
    clearButton: true,
    date: false
});
```