# how to disable past time in bootstrap timepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-timepicker

```
$('.time_popup').timepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    showMeridian: false,
                    maxHours: 24,
                    // pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
                    minuteStep: 5,
                    minDate: moment(),
                    defaultTime: 'current'
                });


this is my jquery code for displaying time picker.
```

How can i disable current dates current time and past time

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Please refer following link that may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716211/how-to-restrict-the-bootstrap-timepicker-min-time-and-max-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable past dates from today in bootstrap datetimepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915213/how-to-disable-past-dates-from-today-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: Look at his question he is using timepicker not datetimepicker.